# How to determine which user is causing SELECT PERMISSION DENIED

Tags: sql-server, logging, permissions

Im using SQL Server 2014. When I get error 'SELECT PERMISSION DENIED' it appears in the SQL Server Error Log but I can't find which user is causing it.

For some reason I'm not able to catch this error in SQL Profiler. I try catching 'User Error' in profiler and filter by [like '%permission%'], but nothing comes up. Also I dont see this information in the log. There is no 'User' column.

I need any way of determining which user is causing this error. Either using profiler or log or alerts, anything.

Comment: Please check SQL Server Error log, you will get permission denied error log with user, host,...

Comment: At the moment looking at log I see such columns: Date, Source, Message, Log Type, Log Source. How can I find the user? Im using SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using Extended Events. I selected event: errorlog_written and filtered by word 'permission'. Also turns out it is possible to catch this error in Profiler, only you have to select Errors and Warning/EventLog. The problem with Profiler that it slows down server considerably. But using Extened Events it is possible to watch the process live.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that your problem can be solved with [SQL Server Audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017).

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO
SELECT @@version;
GO
USE AdventureWorks2016CTP3;
GO
IF EXISTS(SELECT *
          FROM sys.database_audit_specifications
          WHERE [name] = 'SelectFromPassword') BEGIN
  ALTER DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION SelectFromPassword WITH (STATE = OFF);
  DROP DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION SelectFromPassword;
END;
GO
USE master;
GO
IF EXISTS(SELECT *
          FROM sys.server_audits
          WHERE [name] = 'MyServerAudit') BEGIN
  ALTER SERVER AUDIT MyServerAudit WITH (STATE = OFF);
  DROP SERVER AUDIT MyServerAudit;
END;
GO
-- Create the server audit.
CREATE SERVER AUDIT MyServerAudit TO FILE(FILEPATH = 'D:\MyServerAudit');
GO
-- Enable the server audit.
ALTER SERVER AUDIT MyServerAudit WITH (STATE = ON);
GO
USE AdventureWorks2016CTP3;
GO
-- Create the database audit specification.
CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION SelectFromPassword
  FOR SERVER AUDIT MyServerAudit
  ADD (SELECT ON OBJECT::Person.[Password] BY public)
  WITH (STATE = ON);
GO
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'zanjato';
GO
USE AdventureWorks2016CTP3;
GO
SELECT * FROM Person.[Password];
GO
REVERT;
GO
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';
GO
SELECT
  event_time,
  server_principal_name,
  database_principal_name,
  action_id,
  database_name,
  schema_name,
  [object_name],
  [statement]
FROM fn_get_audit_file('D:\MyServerAudit\MyServerAudit*',NULL, NULL)
WHERE succeeded = 0;
GO
ALTER DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION SelectFromPassword WITH (STATE = OFF);
GO
DROP DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION SelectFromPassword;
GO
USE master;
GO
ALTER SERVER AUDIT MyServerAudit WITH (STATE = OFF);
GO
DROP SERVER AUDIT MyServerAudit;
```

**Output:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU4) (KB4024305) - 13.0.4446.0 (X64) 
    Jul 16 2017 18:08:49 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Changed database context to 'AdventureWorks2016CTP3'.
Changed database context to 'master'.
Changed database context to 'AdventureWorks2016CTP3'.
Changed database context to 'AdventureWorks2016CTP3'.
Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 41
The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Password', database 'AdventureWorks2016CTP3', schema 'Person'.
event_time                  server_principal_name database_principal_name action_id database_name          schema_name object_name statement                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
--------------------------- --------------------- ----------------------- --------- ---------------------- ----------- ----------- -------------------------------
2019-02-12 13:28:48.1177803 zanjato               zanjato                 SL        AdventureWorks2016CTP3 Person      Password    SELECT * FROM Person.[Password]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Changed database context to 'master'.
```